# Please make copying code sections easier

Tags: feature-request

Code review questions often contain large chunks of code. Some reviewers like to copy the code into an editor in order to review it locally and to compile it (which is the first stage of any review for me). Copying the code can be tedious when it is many pages long.

It would be useful if each code section had a small 'copy to clipboard' button.

Comment: Yes, CR needs this!